# Hard drive uninitialized when switching enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sata

I have a 3TB SATA drive which I've been using in an external USB enclosure. Today I upgraded the enclosure in order to take advantage of USB 3.0 speeds. However, in this enclosure I am unable to access the drive, and when I go to `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management`, the disk shows as unitialized.

If I switch the drive back to the original enclosure then I am able to access it as before, without any problems.

Is this a common problem for which there is an easy solution, or should I assume my new enclosure is faulty and return it?

Comment: Try another enclosure of the same or (preferably) different make entirely.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem with the enclosur itself.  Have you verified it works wih 3TB drives?